# Android Button color [used shape]

Tags: android, android-layout

res/drawable/circle.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#024ee6"
        android:endColor="#0292e6"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="10dip"
        android:color="#1161b8" />
    <corners android:radius="1000dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />
</shape>
```

In my layout xml there are 2 buttons that use this shape:

```
        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:text="btn 1" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:text="btn 2" />
```

Instead of the button's color that should be, the button's color is purple.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Specify `<android.widget.Button>` or `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>` instead. That unwanted background is likely coming from the Material Components inflater factory that is substituting `MaterialButton`s for plain `<Button>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selected color is replaced with purple due to the use of material components in the application theme, so there are two ways to show the color you want

First : add background tint property to button

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            app:backgroundTint="@null" // this line
            android:text="btn 1" />
```

Second : replace Button to AppCompatButton

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:text="btn 1" />
```